# Simultaneous Linear Congruences With Two Variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, magic-square

(i) Solve the following simultaneous linear congruences: $$17x+23y ≡ 5\mod29$$$$
10x+4y ≡ 11\mod29$$
(ii) If we were filling a 29 × 29 magic square using the uniform step method
$$x_{j} ≡ 16+17j+23 \Bigl[\frac{j}{23}\Bigr]\mod29$$
$$y_{j} ≡ 9+10j+4\Bigl[\frac{j}{29}\Bigr]\mod29$$
Where [...] is the floor function.

What value of j would be placed in the cell with coordinates (21, 20)?

Hint What does (ii) have to do with (i)?

Comment: Do you have also some doubt for part (i)?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to answer part i or ii

Comment: I can give an hint for (i), for (ii) I've not idea how  to deal with

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

For (i), adding up the equations we obtain

$$27(x+y)\equiv 16 \mod {29}$$

Comment: how does this help?

Comment: @EricMaynard you can solve $27(x+y)\equiv 16 \mod {29}$ for $x+y$, indeed by euclidean algorithm we find $14\cdot 27=1+13\cdot 29$ then  $14\cdot 27(x+y)\equiv 14 \cdot 16 \mod {29}\implies x+y\equiv 21 \mod {29}$ then we find $y\equiv 21-x \mod {29}$ and substitute in on of the equations to find $x$